# FFMPEG: Merge two audio and reduce noise in one of them

Tags: sound, ffmpeg, youtube, stream, merge

First audio source is from the camera microphone (which one is too noisy) and another one from a file as background.

This is my two codes that working very well, just not together obviously:

Merged two audio in one stream:

```
ffmpeg -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://............." -stream_loop -1 -i /audio.m4a -filter_complex "[1:a][2:a]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 1:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -b:a 320k -c:a aac -preset veryfast -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/.........
```

Reduce the noise:

```
-af "highpass=f=200, lowpass=f=3000"
```

Any way to get this work together?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Combined command:

```
ffmpeg -rtsp_transport tcp -i "rtsp://input" -re -stream_loop -1 -i audio.m4a -filter_complex "[0:a]highpass=f=200,lowpass=f=3000[mic];[mic][1:a]amix=duration=shortest[a]" -map 1:v -map "[a]" -c:v copy -b:a 320k -c:a aac -f flv "rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/<stream-key>"
```

Changes:

- YouTube needs audio, so `-f lavfi -i anullsrc` is often used to create silent audio for inputs with no audio. But you have audio, so this is not needed. Removed.
- Added `-re` to `audio.m4a` for real-time speed.
- You are stream copying with `-c:v copy`, so `-preset veryfast` is ignored. Removed.
- You can optionally replace lowpass and highpass with `bandpass=f=1400:width_type=h:width=2800`.